# Target framework drop down missing

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working on a C# Windows Universal project. I created a Unit Test project and wanted to add a reference to my first project in the test one. I get the error "Unable to get reference to project". I read that this might be due to .NET target framework mismatch between the projects.

I tried to change the target framework in the Windows Universal project to fix the issue but the drop down does not exist.

I think maybe the drop down not being here is normal, since it's the purpose of a Windows Universal project. But that doesn't help me writing tests.

Comment: You cannot create "any Unit Test project", but a specific Windows Universal one. All other types can give you the mismatch warning.

Comment: I see. I didn't think of going back to my test project creation, sorry.

Comment: Oh and the test project for Windows Universal is NOT in the test subsection of Visual C# projects but in the Windows/Universal